# RDLC formatting number according to locale settings

Tags: c#, asp.net, rdlc

I am using RDLC reports on my web page to show some data as a local report. Everything works fine but the numbers are not formatted according to my locale culture settings (sl-SI) and I am running out of ideas how to fix the problem.

Example. I have a TextBox of value:

- =First(Fields!Count.Value, "PhoneCallsDS")

where “Count”  is integer, and the format is:

- Number
- Use regional formatting = yes
- Decimal places=0
- Use 1000 separator(.)=yes

In the code before the report is populated I set the culture:

```
    CultureInfo cInfo = new CultureInfo(“sl-SI”, false);
    Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = cInfo;
    Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = cInfo;
```

After this I would expect the text box value to be formatted 2.358 as required by the sl-SI culture but is 2,358.

Does anybody knows what I am doing wrong?

Thank you!

Answer (score 9):

I found the solution of this problem, and would like to shere it with the comunity:

1. Go to the RDLC report.
2. Click on the report field (not on the content)
3. Go to the "Properties"
4. Set the "Language" property to your locale (in my case "sl-SI").

That's all.

You can do it programmatically by setting the property "Language" to equal a report parameter having the value of the wished locale ....

Thak you ...

Comment: I setted expression for Language "=First(Fields!CultureName.Value, "QualerServiceOrder")" and got the next exception "The expression used for the language of 'body' refers to a field. Fields cannot be used in report language expressions."

Answer (score 0):

As an addition to Cerkenvic's great answer:

If you set the report's `Language` property to the following expression:

```
=User!Language
```

the RDLC engine will use the current thread's locale without you having to implement and fill a custom report parameter.